# Unable to telnet to another machine

Tags: php, sockets, networking, ip, telnet

I am getting a bit desperate after hours of research:

A Windows 7 computer with a local PHP application that listens to port 12345 with a socket.
From the same Windows 7:

- If I do telnet localhost 12345, the php code sees the connection.
- If I do telnet 127.0.0.1 12345, the php code sees the connection.
- If I do telnet <local_ip_address> 12345, the php code DOES NOT see the connection.
- If I do telnet <dns_name> 12345, the php code DOES NOT see the connection.

From another machine I don't have any connection at all when I use the ip or the dns address.

Doing a telnet from another machine with the same address but on ports 80 or 21 work perfectly.

Even with the local firewall / antivirus disabled I get the same result.
I am using a standard Apple TimeCapsule as access point, but not configured specially, not sure if that can influence for ports > 1024...

Would you have any idea for me ?
Thanks !

Comment: A question better suited for http://superuser.com

Comment: @PaulSasik Actually in this case it indeed was a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really 2 options to get this behavior that I can see;

- Your firewall is enabled (which you tested)
- Your socket is binding to 127.0.0.1 instead of your public IP.

I'd have a look at your local binding, aka the address you give to [`socket_bind()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php).

If it says "127.0.0.1", change it to 0.

Answer (score 2):

`telnet 12345` is trying to connect to a machine whose IP is `12345` decimal, aka `0.0.4.210` in dotted quad format. You cannot use telnet like that - the argument cannot be simply a port number. It'll be interpreted as an IP.

Comment: The `telnet 12345` was a formatting problem in the question with an unescaped `<` ending up hiding the address.